# Claim the collection $\left\{\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right\}$ ($T$ stopping time) is uniformly integrable in the proof of Novikov's Condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, uniform-integrability

Here I have a question in the proof of Novikov's condition from Le Gall's Book Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus Page 137:

The proof is very long, and I only have problem in the following part:

Now we have the following :

> For continuous local matingale $L_{0}=0$ , $0<a<1$, $\mathcal{E}(aL)=\exp\left(aL_{t}-a^{2}\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}\right)$

We have known that it is a continuous local martingale, By Ito's formula. 
My goal is to prove $\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}$, where $T$ is stopping time, is uniformly integrable. One important inequality in the proof is:

> $$E\left[1_{\Gamma}\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]\leqslant E\left[1_{\Gamma}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]^{2a(1-a)}$$
>   For $\Gamma:=\left\{\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}>x,x>0\right\}$

I have known that $\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)$ is uniformly integrable, then how can I derive that $\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}$ is also uniformly integrable? (Le Gall's book has omitted this part.)

Comment: The exponent $2a(1-a)$ is outside the expectation, is it? And you want the uniform integrability with respect to $a$, $T$ or both?

Comment: Yes, the exponent is outside the expectation, and $a$ is a parameter, the uniform integrability should be verified w.r.t. $T$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_R:=\left\{ \exp \left(L_T/2\right) \gt R\right\}$ where $R$ is fixed. Then 
$$
\mathbb E\left[1_{\Gamma}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]=
\mathbb E\left[1_{\Gamma}1_{E_R}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]
+\mathbb E\left[1_{\Gamma}1_{E_R^c}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]\\
\leqslant \mathbb E\left[1_{E_R}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]
+R\mathbb P\left(\Gamma\right).
$$
Let us fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$. Since the family $\left\{\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right), T\mbox{ is a stopping time}\right\}$ is uniformly integrable, we can choose $R_\varepsilon$ such that $\mathbb E\left[1_{E_R}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]\lt \varepsilon$.
Moreover, we have 
$$
\mathbb E\left[ \mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]\leqslant \mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]^{2a(1-a)}
$$
by letting $x$ going to $0$  hence $S:=\sup_T\mathbb E\left[ \mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]$ is finite. In particular, by Markov's inequality, $P\left(\Gamma\right)\leqslant S/x$.

We thus have 
$$
\sup_T\mathbb E\left[1_{\Gamma}\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]\leqslant \varepsilon^{2a(1-a)}+\left(\frac{R_\varepsilon S}x\right)^{2a(1-a)}
$$
hence 
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sup_T\mathbb E\left[1_{\Gamma}\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]\leqslant \varepsilon^{2a(1-a)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, in Le Gall's book, it only shows the causality without any additional explanation, I have consulted notes which are adpated from the book  (Paul Bougade's notes and MATH 7245 from GaTech), however, they still did not explain it.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is some easier way to derive the conclusion by the given inequality, otherwise we can also prove independent of this inequality that $\mathcal{E}(aL)$ is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^{p}$, which also implies the uniform integrability.

Comment: An other way could be the following: uniform integrability of $\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)$ implies that there is some $\delta$ such that if we integrate one of these random variables on a set of measure smaller than $\delta$, we get something smaller than $\varepsilon$. For $x$ large enough, $\Gamma$ is of measure smaller than $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is just to verify the definition of uniform integrability:

By the uniform integrability of $\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)$, for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that for $\mathbb{P}(\Gamma)<\delta$, $E\left[1_{\Gamma}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}L_{T}\right)\right]<\epsilon$. 
Considering the the inequality given in the question, we can also derive that $E\left[1_{\Gamma}\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]\leqslant\epsilon^{2a(1-a)}$ for such $\Gamma$. Then notice that $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily chosen, then the uniformly integrability of $E\left[1_{\Gamma}\mathcal{E}(aL)_{T}\right]$ has been verified.

Also, notice that $\Gamma$ can be chosen arbitrarily in $\mathcal{F}$, and the uniformly integrability only verifies certain classes of $\Gamma$.